# How would you describe a sound "appearing"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

The idea behind something *appearing* is more visual in nature; it comes into sight.

What would I say if something "appeared audibly"? The sound of the oncoming car appeared to my ears!

[Synonyms for appear](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/appear?r=76&src=ref&ch=the) all seem to stick to visual, material, or abstract concepts; nothing for auditory elements stand out.

Comment: This comment is not intended as a criticism for your question: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/to-make-a-sound

Comment: I suspect any word that is generic enough to apply to all sounds will be unappealing.  We have a myriad of words to describe the act of a sound being made, but I think they're mostly specific to a particular form of sound.  For consideration, look at the answer provided by @centaurus.  An engine thrums, a car comes (and goes.)   Or consider instead http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia and the verbs "oink" "meow" and "roar."  Each of these verbs can be used to describe the appearance of a particular sound.

Comment: *Appear* has many senses, but presumably OP is focused on the *to become visible* meaning. Which can be paralleled by *to become **audible***, but it's not really a direct equivalent because a *sight* can suddenly manifest itself (subject was looking elsewhere or had his eyes closed, object was concealed *behind* something, etc.). But a *sound* is either there or it isn't - we can't listen in the wrong direction or close our ears, and a sound source remains audible even if it's "hiding" behind a tree. So the question itself is unsound - effectively, *there is no equivalent "auditory" term*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you open a door or window, the sounds on the other side will become audible. Also, as something comes closer, its sound increases in volume, which is somewhat analogous.

Comment: A sight appears - and is then seen. A sound sounds - and is then heard.

Comment: ^ lol classic example of a comment that should have been an answer

Comment: Not sure that appear means to come into visual "consciousness"; perhaps: appear means to come into view. And perhaps you mean to become aware of a sound or sight. Visual awareness.

Comment: @NigelJ  aha! See no evil, **hear** no evil, speak no evil!  If a tree falls in the forest ....

Comment: @DanielThompson hear was lately made an answer. Nigel is generous!

Comment: Need to make the Title question match the first sentence as the definition for appear has nothing to do with consciousness but the ability for it to be registered.  Visually perceptible is different than the act of perception itself.  ie ( John turned his head to look after the deer appeared from behind above the tree )

Comment: So, you're looking for a word that means "perceive via hearing".  There are various words like *perceive*, *pick up*, *catch* that mean something becomes perceptible, but don't specify hearing as the sense being used.  Some answers here focus on the sending of the sound, rather than the receiving of it...

Comment: Good discussion on a more recent duplicate question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450913/what-is-the-aural-equivalent-to-the-word-appear/450938?noredirect=1#comment1085643_450938

Comment: All of the given answers are only audio versions of _appear_, none work for _appearance_. You can't say a person made an _appearance_ at a show if it was only an audio call and none of the answers below work for this situation, they're only for the verb form, not the noun form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick with simplicity. I propose **[go](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/go).**<sub>(Oxford, sense 4.2)</sub>

> Make a sound of a specified kind:
>
> *the engine went bang*
>
> *The elevator went ping and the doors opened.*

*It was dark. I couldn't see anything. Suddenly, I heard a gun go bang.*

Speaking of guns, **go off** is related:

> (Of a gun, bomb, or similar device) explode or fire:
>
> (Of an alarm) begin to sound.

*And then, I heard an alarm go off in the distance.*

---

In case you're not still convinced, [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmRUq1bWyPo).

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're asking for the sound equivalent of:

A light *appeared* in the forest

---

## [Emerge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emerged)

> to become manifest : become known

- A sound *emerged* from the forest

Comment: and emergence is not registered till heard

Comment: @lbf, "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?"

Comment: @user28434 ... most certainty. you though may not hear it!

Comment: @Ibf and appearance is not registered till seen :)

Comment: Sure, it's correct usage, but I feel like this risks sounding unnatural. In my reckoning 'emerge' sounds almost volitional and is better used with beings, ideas, etc. Not only that but I feel like it applies to visual cues more than auditory ones.

Answer (score 5):

Along with "arise" or "emerge," you could use "ring out."

"Pistol shots ring out in the barroom night."

Or, along with those, and if you aren't talking about a sound, you could use sound as a verb. Like this:

"The trumpets sounded from the other side of the room."

But maybe don't say: "The sound sounded from the other side of the room." Unless you're after that.

Comment: +1, I'm going to have to start using Dylan lyrics as examples.

Answer (score 4):

A word that's sometimes used is *arise*. As in the line from [*A Visit From Saint Nicholas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Visit_from_St._Nicholas):

> When out on the lawn there arose such a clatter,
>   I sprang from my bed to see what was the matter.

Comment: Did you write that on-the-fly?

Comment: No, I copied it from a web site. But it's so well known, I didn't think I needed to cite it.

Comment: It's the first I've heard it. Still, nice to see examples which add a little something :)

Comment: Maybe because you're from India. In America it's one of the most well known Christmas poems. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Visit_from_St._Nicholas

Comment: I see. Christmas sounds lovely. Wish we had it here!

Answer (score 4):

Along with "emerge", you could use "arise"

[Arise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arise)

> a : to begin to occur or to exist : to come into being or to attention

[Emerged is taking over in usage, though](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sound+emerged%2Csound+arose&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csound%20emerged%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csound%20arose%3B%2Cc0), vs. arose, when paired with "sound"

You might try looking up the comparison for your specific example.

#### Edit

To clarify the difference between verbs that reference the production or perception of a sound or image:

Like [appear](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appear) (and [emerge](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/450915/301781)), arise references the perception of its subject (to come in sight, to come into attention, to become known).

> Appear, 1 a : to be or come in sight
>
> when the sun appears on the horizon

Compare to the verb [sound](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sound), which references the moment of sound production

> *transitive verb* 1 a : to cause to sound
>
> sound a trumpet
>
> *intransitive verb* 1 a: to make a sound

Comment: Good call on the distinction that "sound" is different from appear ! I agree with you there that "sound" is not "able to be heard" but "production of a noise".  A car approaching does not "sound" at the point you can hear it but it does appear at the point you can see it.

Comment: @Tom22 I think the OP is just trying to be more precise about what sense of  appear s/he is looking for.  I understand *to come in sight* as coming into visual awareness.  [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/appear) uses *become visible or noticeable*.  You notice something visible when it comes into visual consciousness. That's my read, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

**Emanated**

You can have "a person *appeared* from behind the wall" as well as "a sound *emanated* from behind the wall".

Answer (score 3):

*"Appear means to come into visual consciousness"*

and

[**Hear**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?ei=6WIoW7L_OoW20QSWx5QQ&q=hear&oq=hear&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1l4j0i131k1l2j0l2j0i10k1j0i131k1.276471.276471.0.277623.1.1.0.0.0.0.551.551.5-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.549....0.p4fu7QlE12M)  means to "perceive with the ear the sound made by (someone or something)."

"Behind her she could hear men's voices"
verb: hear; 3rd person present: hears; past tense: heard; past participle: heard; gerund or present participle: hearing

Comment: The analogous word for 'hear' in visual context would be 'see', so I don't agree with your answer.

Comment: +1  to hear is elegantly simple ... most other words are embellishment and matters of opinion @Bakabaka

Comment: @Ibf I agree that using *to hear* would generally make for a better sentence, since it's transitive (vs. appear, which is intransitive)

Comment: hear is to see as   ____ is to  appear.  The two do not go together.   I hear the sound, I see the elephant .   The bell can be heard and the elephant can be seen (but need past particle with the 'can'?).   However He appeared the elephant doesn't work -  the elephant appearing and it being seen are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

When used as a verb [sound](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sound) can mean (ODO):

> Emit or cause to emit sound
>
> [no object]: *a loud buzzer sounded*
>
> [with object]: *she sounded the horn*

Similarly to the way *to appear* is used for visible objects, e.g.

> A magnificent sight appeared in front of their eyes

there are examples of usage for *to sound*

> *This chiming... Which I've had sounding in my ears for ten years*

from: [Strindberg and the Five Senses](https://books.google.rs/books?id=4CdQiY82FeAC&pg=PA73&dq=sound+%22in+my+ears%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QgpNVej6KIqysQHL74DADQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sound%20%22in%20my%20ears%22&f=false) by Hans-Goran Ekman

or

> *Another and other hoofs than Puck's **sounded** in my ears close ... and crushed against mo-a sharp pain smote through my chest—a roar **sounded** in my ears- horses seemed to be about and around me on every side, and it was all darkness.*

from: [London Society, Volume 8; Volume 10](https://books.google.rs/books?id=aPNTAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA17&dq=%22sounded+in+my+ears%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cQ1NVc6pGIeNsAGG64D4CQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sounded%20in%20my%20ears%22&f=false) James Hogg, Florence Marryat

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

## Fade-In; or, Coalesce

Per the OED, **Fade-in** is:

> ...the gradual... increase in the brightness or definition of a picture or the loudness of a sound.

A more poetic, if not literal, word would be **Coalesce**:

> To bring together, merge; to combine (parts or elements) to form one whole.

Though it does not use the word *Coalesce*, I always think of Salieri's quote from *Amadeus*, which I think captures the spirit of it:

> On the page it looked nothing. The beginning simple, almost comic. Just a pulse, bassoons and basset horns, like a rusty squeezebox. Then suddenly; high above it, an oboe, a single note, hanging there unwavering, till a clarinet took over and sweetened it into a phrase of such delight!

Comment: The fade-in nature of the a "spirit", "angel", or "entity" materializing or manifesting gradually in front of you really is appropos for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

"The sound became audible."  Other ways it could be phrased are:  "I began to hear the sound of ...", "I became aware of the sound of ...", "The sound of ... slowly entered my awareness." or possibly "The silence was broken by the sound of ..."

Answer (score 0):

- "A faint noise which quickly evolved into the thrumming of an engine."
- "I could hear the faint noise of a car coming in the distance."
- "A faint noise which quickly turned into the distant sound of a car coming down the road."

Answer (score 0):

Resound -
re·sound
rəˈzound/Submit
verb
1.
(of a sound, voice, etc.) fill a place with sound; be loud enough to echo.
"another scream resounded through the school"
synonyms:   echo, re-echo, reverberate, ring out, boom, thunder, rumble
"the explosion resounded around the silent street"

Alternatively a source independent descriptor for something to appear, emerge, or develop could be the word *arrive* which could apply to sound.

Answer (score -1):

## Crescendo

Depending on what you're after, then crescendo might be what you want.

From https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crescendo:

> Verb. To increase in intensity, to reach or head for a crescendo.

An example from http://www.dictionary.com/browse/crescendo:

> Then his ears caught a crescendo of the whispering that he had heard before.
>
> *The Whispering Spheres, Russell Robert Winterbotham*

Comment: It's the "catching" (caught) that the OP's asking for.